# Как использовать Pip непосредственно из python скрипта?

Tags: python, pip

К примеру как работать с pip через командную строку понятно:

```
pip install some_package
```

А вот как можно проверить установлен ли определенный пакет или нет, и если не установлен то установить его, и все это чтобы выполнялось в python скрипте?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Рекомендованный путь использования pip внутри скрипта](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program) — запуск pip как внешней команды:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys

package = 'some_package'
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package])
```

Если пакет не установлен, то эта команда попытается его установить. Если пакет установлен, то более новая версия не будет ставиться. Если хотите самую новую версию поставить, то [`--upgrade` можно передать](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-u).

Отдельно команду по проверке установлен или нет пакет, если вы хотите чтобы у вас был установлен этот пакет, нет необходимости запускать.

Если не хотите видеть вывод `pip` команды, можно `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` передать. Чтобы stderr в то же место перенаправить, можно `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Пожно просто импортировать его:

```
    import pip

    def install(package):
        pip.main(['install', package])
```

Comment: [*"you must not use pip's internal APIs in this way."*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program)

Answer (score -3):

Я бы попробовал через `try except` запустить `subprocess` :

```
try:
  call(pip install some_packeges)
```

Для всех моих целей, где нужна была командная строка он помогал.